# How to populate a select list in a Django Template dynamically using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-views, html-select

I've recently been learning Django and HTML but I'm completely new to JavaScript. I'm having a go at creating a database display page with a filter menu at the side. For this page I have the following code:

Model.py:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    PartID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    SiteID = models.ForeignKey('Site', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    Subtype = models.ForeignKey('Subtype', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    ConnectedTo= models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True)
    BatchNo = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, null=True)
    SerialNo = models.CharField(max_length=32,blank=True)
    Manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, null=True)
    Length = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    InspectionPeriod = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    LastInspected = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    InspectionDue = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

View.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def sites(request, site):

    siteselected = site
    warnings = 0
    expired = 0
    good = 0
    PartsAtSite = Part.objects.filter(SiteID = siteselected)
    TypesList = Type.objects.values_list('TypeName', flat=True).distinct()
    InspectionList = Part.objects.values_list('InspectionPeriod', flat=True).distinct()
    LengthList = Part.objects.values_list('Length', flat=True).distinct()
    LocationList = Part.objects.values_list('Location', flat=True).distinct()
    ManufacturerList = Part.objects.values_list('Manufacturer', flat=True).distinct()

    for part in PartsAtSite:
        if part.LastInspected == None:
            part.InspectionDue = "Yes"
            expired = expired + 1

        else:
            Deadline = part.LastInspected + timedelta(days=part.InspectionPeriod)

        if datetime.now().date() > Deadline:
            part.InspectionDue = "Yes"
            expired = expired + 1

        elif datetime.now().date() > (Deadline - timedelta(days=30)):
            part.InspectionDue = "<30 Days"
            warnings = warnings + 1
        else:
            part.InspectionDue = "No"
            good = good + 1
    part.save()

    context = {
        'TypesList': TypesList,
        'InspectionList': InspectionList,
        'LengthList': LengthList,
        'LocationList': LocationList,
        'ManufacturerList': ManufacturerList,
        'PartsAtSite': PartsAtSite,
        'expired': expired,
        'warnings': warnings,
        'good': good,
        'SiteName': Site.objects.get(SiteID = siteselected).SiteName,
        'SiteNo': Site.objects.get(SiteID = siteselected).SiteID,
    }

template = loader.get_template('myproject/sites.html')
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

And the HTML for my filter div:

```
<div id="filterdiv" class="dark">
    <center><h3>Filters</h3></center>
    <br>

    <center>Type</center>
    <select name="Types">
        <option>All</option>
        {% for types in TypesList %}
            <option>{{types}}</option>
        {%endfor%}
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>

    <center>Inspection Period</center>
    <select name="Inspection Period">
        <option>All</option>
        {% for inspections in InspectionList %}
            <option>{{inspections}}</option>
        {%endfor%}
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>

    <center>Length</center>
    <select name="Length">
        <option>All</option>
        {% for lengths in LengthList %}
            <option>{{lengths}}</option>
        {%endfor%}
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>

    <center>Location</center>
    <select name="Location">
        <option>All</option>
        {% for locations in LocationList %}
            <option>{{locations}}</option>
        {%endfor%}
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>

    <center>Manufacturer</center>
    <select name="Manufacturer">
        <option>All</option>
        {% for manufacturers in ManufacturerList %}
            <option>{{manufacturers}}</option>
        {%endfor%}
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button>Apply Filter (TODO)</button>
    <button>Reset Filters (TODO)</button>
</div>
```

I am able to fill the lists just fine, but I want to be able to change it so that when I open the `Type` drop down box after selecting a `Manufacturer`, then I only get offered a list of `Type`s from that `Manufacturer`.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the model for `Type`?

Comment: 1) In your code there is no connection to be seen between `Type` and `Manufacturer` (I suppose it has something to do with `Subtype`, but I don't think that `Subtype` = `TypeName`). So, there is no way to filter `Type` based on `Manufacturer` 2) And in the comment to the post of @JesusFung you wrote the opposite of what is in your post - that you need to filter the other way around `Manufacturer` based on `Type`. So, please, clarify these points and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I need both ways. Lets say I have a list of 10 items with all the columns mentioned above. The `select` boxes to filter for each column are filled **only with the values used in that column** rather than all total possibilities. I want that functionality to continue following a filter. So if we filter for Type A, and there are no Type A's with Manufacturer C, then Manufacturer C is dropped from the `select`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are talking about "chained dropdowns feature".

In Django you can do it using `django-select2` library easy.

https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra.html#interdependent-select2

I am sure you can google a lot of solutions and methods of how to do it in any programming language and, of course, in Python + Django.

Just a few good examples articles from me I hope :)

- https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html
- https://github.com/sibtc/dependent-dropdown-example
- https://www.devinterface.com/en/blog/how-to-implement-two-dropdowns-dependent-on-each-other-using-django-and-jquery
- http://sayhelloworld.co/dependent-dropdown-with-pre-checked-fields/

Other libraries (from google)

- https://pypi.org/project/django-clever-selects/
- https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects
- https://github.com/s-block/django-chained-selectbox
- https://django-selectable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#chained-selection

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript, you could add `event listeners` on your select elements that will trigger a request to your python backend. However you will have to edit the view so that it returns only data (usually in JSON format) in order to know which options you hide or not. Below code suppose that the view returns a simple list, you'll probably have to edit it.

```
document.getElementById("yourSelect").addEventListener("change", function () {
    // add a handler to the change event
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        other_select = document.getElementById("anotherSelect");
    req.open("POST", "yourUrl", true);
    // you will need to use json.loads in python code
    req.send(JSON.stringify({value: this.value}));
    req.onreadystatechange = function (res) {
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
            // the request is done and server returned 200 success code
            for (let i in other_select.children){
                let opt = other_select.children[i];
                if(res.indexOf(opt.value) > -1 ){
                    // shows the option if previously hidden
                    opt.style.display = "block";
                }else{
                    // hides the option
                    opt.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```