# Set dynamic values from a dictionary for select values inside a Django template using Javascript or other method

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have three consecutive select options that their values change according to the previous select. The purpose is to categorize products using these select options. First option is to either categorize products with their `usage` or `model` value. If `usage` is selected as the first `select` option, then the second `select` that is populated with `usage`s list which is all objects of the `Usage` model, is shown, and if `model` is selected, then the select populated with all objects of `MainModel` model is shown and the other `select` tag gets hidden with `visually-hidden` class.

To this point, my codes are as below:

views.py:

```
def get_common_queryset():
    usage_queryset = Usage.objects.all()
    main_model_queryset = MainModel.objects.all()
    sub_usage_queryset = SubUsage.objects.all()
    pump_type_queryset = PumpType.objects.all()
    queryset_dictionary = {
        "usage_queryset": usage_queryset,
        "main_model_queryset": main_model_queryset,
        "sub_usage_queryset": sub_usage_queryset,
        "pump_type_queryset": pump_type_queryset,
    }
    return queryset_dictionary

def solution_main(request):
    context  = get_common_queryset()
    return render(request, "solutions/solution_main.html", context)
```

my template:

```
<div class="col-md-3 mx-md-5">
    <h2 class="h5 nm-text-color fw-bold mb-4">Choose usage or model:</h2>
    <select required aria-label="Select usage or model"
            id="usage_model_select" class="form-select" onchange="set_usage_or_model_dic()">
        <option>----</option>
        <option value="usage">Usage</option>
        <option value="model">Model</option>
    </select>
</div>

{#  usage or model select div #}
<div class="col-md-3 mx-md-5">

{#  usage select div #}
    <div class="usage visually-hidden" id="usage_div">
        <h2 class="h5 nm-text-color fw-bold mb-4">Select usage:</h2>
        <select required aria-label="Select usage" class="form-select"
                name="usage_select" onchange="set_sub_usage_list()" id="usage_select_id">
            <option selected>----</option>
            {% for usage in usage_queryset %}
                <option value="{{ usage.id }}">{{ usage.usage_name_fa }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>

{#  model select div #}
    <div class="model visually-hidden" id="model_div">
        <h2 class="h5 nm-text-color fw-bold mb-4">Select model:</h2>
        <select required aria-label="Select model" class="form-select"
                name="model_select" onchange="set_pump_type_list()" id="model_select_id">
            <option selected>----</option>
            {% for model in main_model_queryset %}
                <option value="{{ model.id }}">{{ model.model_name_fa }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

{# select sub_usage or pump_type div #}
<div class="col-md-3 mx-md-5">

{#  sub_usage select div #}
    <div class="sub_usage visually-hidden" id="sub_usage_div">
        <h2 class="h5 nm-text-color fw-bold mb-4">Select sub-usage:</h2>
        <select required aria-label="Select sub_usage" class="form-select" name="sub_usage_select">
            <option selected>All sub-usages from this usage</option>
            {% for sub_usage in sub_usage_queryset %}
                <option value="{{ sub_usage.id }}">{{ sub_usage.sub_usage_name_fa }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>

{#  model select div #}
    <div class="pump-type visually-hidden" id="pump_type_div">
        <h2 class="h5 nm-text-color fw-bold mb-4">Select pump type:</h2>
        <select aria-label="Select pump_type" class="form-select" name="pump_type_select">
            <option selected>All pump types of this model</option>
            {% for pump_type in pump_type_queryset %}
                <option value="{{ pump_type.id }}">{{ pump_type.type_name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</div>
```

(I'm using JS to show/hide specific divs with removing/adding `visually-hidden` class)

But, I don't want to use `sub_usage_queryset = SubUsage.obects.all()`, I want to see which `usage` (or `model`) is selected in the previous stage and populate the next `select` according to this choice.

The solution that I have in mind is that since there are few `usage`s and `main_model`s, I can create a dictionary for each that contains different `usage`s or `main_model`s as keys, and their `sub_usage`s or `pump_type`s as a list for their value. As an example for `usage`s:

```
sub_usage_list = {}
for usage in Usage.objects.all():
    usage_sub_usage_list = SubUsage.objects.filter(usage=usage)
    sub_usage_list[usage] = usage_sub_usage_list
```

So `sub_usage_list` will contain each `usage` as a key, and that `usage`'s `sub_usage`s as a list for that key's value.

I don't know if this approach is correct, and even if it is, I don't know how to use specific sub_usage list from this dictionary accoring to the selected value in the relating `select` option. I'm not very familiar with JS, So I'd very much appreciate your help and tips.

NOTE: As you can see, I'm using server side rendering, so I don't know how to do this without refreshing the page.

Comment: There is a method in django using django-select2. See the soloution of this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105644/how-to-populate-a-select-list-in-a-django-template-dynamically-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you want without refreshing the page it is necessary to use AJAX.

Starting with your template. Since you are going to populate dynamically based on choices, it is not necessary to have one box for each QuerySet. You can clear and repopulate them using JS.

templates.html:

```
<body>
    <div class="col-md-3 mx-md-5">
        <h2 class="h5 nm-text-color fw-bold mb-4">Choose usage or model:</h2>
        <select required aria-label="Select usage or model"
                id="usage_model_select" class="form-select" onchange="populate_lists()">
            <option value="" selected>----</option>
            <option value="usage">Usage</option>
            <option value="model">Model</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    
    {#  usage or model select div #}
    <div class="col-md-3 mx-md-5">
        {#  usage select div #}
        <div class="usage visually-hidden" id="usage_div">
            <h2 class="h5 nm-text-color fw-bold mb-4">Select options:</h2>
            <select required aria-label="Select usage" class="form-select"
                    name="usage_select" onchange="populate_lists()" id="select_options">
                <option value="" selected>----</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    {# select sub_usage or pump_type div #}
    <div class="col-md-3 mx-md-5">
        {#  sub_usage select div #}
        <div class="sub_usage visually-hidden" id="sub_usage_div">
            <h2 class="h5 nm-text-color fw-bold mb-4">Sub selection:</h2>
            <select required aria-label="Select sub_usage" class="form-select" id="sub_usage_select" name="sub_usage_select">
                <option selected>All sub-selections</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Next" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</body>
```

templates.html `<script>`: ([CSRF with AJAX](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/csrf/#using-csrf-protection-with-ajax) | [Get Select element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085810/7100120) | [Populate Select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674618/adding-options-to-select-with-javascript) | [Clear Select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364493/how-do-i-clear-all-options-in-a-dropdown-box))

```
<script>
    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    // Clear SelectionBoxes
    function removeOptions(selectElement, initial) {
        var i, L = selectElement.options.length - 1;
        for(i = L; i >= 0; i--) {
            selectElement.remove(i);
        }
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = "";
        opt.innerHTML = initial;
        selectElement.appendChild(opt);
    }

    function populate_lists() {
        const url = '/solution/ajax/';
        const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

        var e = document.getElementById("usage_model_select");
        var selectedOption = e.value;
        if (selectedOption == "" ) {
            removeOptions(document.getElementById("select_options"), "----");
            removeOptions(document.getElementById("sub_usage_select"), "All sub-usages from this usage");
            return
        }

        var e = document.getElementById("select_options");
        var option = e.value;
        if (option == "" ) {
            option = null
        }
        
        // Send AJAX Request
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "select": selectedOption,
                "option": option,
            }),
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            var select = document.getElementById("select_options");
            removeOptions(select, "----");
            var selected_usage_name = null

            for (var i = 0; i<=data.select.length-1; i++){
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = data.select[i]['id'];
                opt.innerHTML = data.select[i]['name'];
                
                if (data.select[i]['id'] == data.selected_option) {
                    selected_usage_name = data.select[i]['name'];
                    opt.selected = true
                }
                select.appendChild(opt);
            }

            if (data.sub_select != null) {
                var select = document.getElementById("sub_usage_select");
                removeOptions(select, `All sub-usages from ${selectedOption} ${selected_usage_name}`);

                for (var i = 0; i<=data.sub_select.length-1; i++){
                    var opt = document.createElement('option');
                    opt.value = data.sub_select[i]['id'];
                    opt.innerHTML = data.sub_select[i]['name'];
                    select.appendChild(opt);
                }
                console.log(data.sub_select)
            }
            
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    }
</script>
```

views.py:

```
def solution_ajax(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    sub_select = None

    if data['select'] == 'usage':
        select = list(Usage.objects.all().values())

        if data['option'] is not None:
            sub_select = list(SubUsage.objects.filter(usage__id=data['option']).values())

    elif data['select'] == 'model':
        select = list(MainModel.objects.all().values())

        if data['option'] is not None:
            sub_select = list(PumpType.objects.filter(model__id=data['option']).values())

    return JsonResponse({
        'select': select,
        'selected_option': data['option'],
        'sub_select': sub_select,
    })
    

def solution_main(request):
    return render(request, "solutions/solution_main.html")
```

Note, I've made some extra features such as clearing the select options, although not for all events.

Merry xmas.